# code helper for c programming

Tags: c, visual-studio, helper

Are there any plugins for visual studio (any version) or any other ide that can show you the standard library function prototypes and their (examples) , return etc for the standard c library... much like the java code helper found in eclipse if I am not mistaken (I am not a java developer but I think I saw something similar to what I described).

note: I know I can use google or msdn but I am asking about other alternatives.

Comment: Standard IntelliSense should give you function prototypes (by "standard library" I assume you meant Win32 and C APIs). As far as the documentation goes, I don't think you can get it, and even less sure about examples, since even MSDN descriptions often lack samples.

Comment: As Alek said, Intellisense should already be giving you this. If you want examples and full explanations, pressing F1 should get you that (though on some VS setups that can be slower than it really should be - especially on the first time). Is there something different you're looking for?

Comment: Yes intellisense gives you the prototypes but not an example, and yes you can press F1 but I want an inline helper. without living the source code editor window

Comment: Visual Studio's intellisense and refactoring support for C & C++ pale in comparison with the support for .Net languages. This is somewhat understandable given the edit in my answer, but it definitely leaves me wanting.

Answer (score 6):

[Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) is by far the best C/C++ improvement for Visual Studio.

**Edit** in response to userHel's comment:

> I'll give it a shot. but how come nobody came up with a free version

Probably because it's really hard to do well. You practically need an entire compiler just to parse C++ sufficiently to give the kinds of features VA-X does. At the other end of the stack, you would also need an almost flawless integration with Visual Studio. Just imagine what's in between...

This is where firstborn selling comes in...

Comment: are there any free alternatives?

Comment: Try the free trial. After thirty days you will sell your firstborn to pay for it.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. but how come nobody came up with a free version

Answer (score 0):

[KDevelop4](http://www.kdevelop.org/) has good C++ analysis support which is constantly improving, including features which I think were inspired by VAX. I haven't used VAX so I can't comment on feature parity, but it has all the C++ features I need. Of note is the tooltip when holding the mouse over an identifier, which gives type info as well as links to the definition (and declaration if available).

Answer (score 0):

For linux development, the man pages are excellent. I'd like to know of something similar for Windows.